# DataGridView not being populated with the DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

For some odd reason, the DataGridView is not being populated with the table from the data source. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The data set DOES have a table.

```
private void BtnViewUncommittedDataClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtnNewBusiness.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateGridForNewBusiness();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Logger.LogError(ex.Source, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), ex.Message);
            Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateGridForNewBusiness()
{
    dgvDetail.DataSource = Database.GetNewBusinessDetailJobData();
    dgvSummary.DataSource = Database.GetNewBusinessSummaryJobData();
    dgvDetailNYD.DataSource = Database.GetNewBusinessDetailJobDataNyd();
    dgvSummaryNYD.DataSource = Database.GetNewBusinessSummaryJobDataNyd();
    lblDetailRowCountlbl.Text = "";
    lblDetailNYDRowCountlbl.Text = "";
    lblSummaryRowCountlbl.Text = "";
    lblSummaryNYDRowCountlbl.Text = "";
    lblDetailRowCountlbl.Text = "New Business Detail - Row Count:";
    lblDetailNYDRowCountlbl.Text = "New Business Detail NYD - Row Count:";
    lblSummaryRowCountlbl.Text = "New Business Summary - Row Count:";
    lblSummaryNYDRowCountlbl.Text = "New Business Summary NYD - Row Count:";
    lblDetailRowCount.Text = dgvDetail.Rows.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    lblSummaryRowCount.Text = dgvSummary.Rows.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    lblDetailNYDRowCount.Text = dgvDetailNYD.Rows.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    lblSummaryNYDRowCount.Text = dgvSummaryNYD.Rows.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Just showing you the first query method as the others are the same:

```
public static DataSet GetNewBusinessDetailJobData()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetNewBusinessDetailJobData", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (var ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, data IS being pulled but for some reason, the DataGridView does not change. It's simply gray.

Comment: i figured out the issue... i cannot set the datasource to a dataset. it has to be a data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I cannot set the DataSource of a DataGridView to be a DataSet. It has to be a DataTable.